# Order a Django queryset in ascending order but with 0-valued items at the end

Tags: python, django, sorting, django-queryset, django-orm

I am new to python, django. What I am trying to do is that I have a model defined as products which has two columns: name and price.

```
name    price
pen      20
paper    30
eraser   0
```

I am trying to sort them using the following code:

```
Product.objects.all().order_by('-price')
```

This sorts the values as `0,20,30`.

The model code is

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.IntegerField('Price', blank=True, null=True)
```

What I am trying to achieve is to sort it as `20,30,0` with 0 being appended at the end.

Is there any function with which I can achieve it?

Comment: Show us your models code please.

Comment: this is the model

class Product(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
   price = models.IntegerField('Price', blank=True, null=True)

Comment: Could you please use the edit link to provide additional details to your question instead of adding them as comment.

Comment: @wtower added code in description

Comment: wouldn't it "-price" => [30, 20, 0]? Do you mean order_by("price")?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could order by a calculated value in case you *really* want to do everything on the DB level. This should work:

```
Product.objects.all().order_by(\
        Case(When(price=0, then=Value(MAX_INT)), default=F('price')))
```

Where `MAX_INT=2147483647` is the value of a 32 bit signed integer which is [safe on all Django-supported DBs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#integerfield).

Answer (score 5):

The following could work, it's not the nicest code to implement but for your special case I think this is the easy way to do it using queryset directly, otherwise you can think about implementing it in Python(sorted or other builtin functions)

```
qs = Product.objects.exclude(price=0).order_by('-price') | Product.objects.filter(price=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to achieve is this SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY price = 0, price;
```

With Django's ORM, use [extra()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra) filter modifier:

```
Product.objects.extra(select={"custom":"price = 0"}, order_by=["custom","price"]).all()
```

Answer (score 1):

> [Conditional Expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/conditional-expressions/) let you use if ... elif ... else logic within filters, annotations, aggregations, and updates. A conditional expression evaluates a series of conditions for each row of a table and returns the matching result expression.

```
from django.db.models import IntegerField, Case, Value, When

MAX_INT = 2147483647
Product.objects.annotate(
    my_price=Case(
        When(price=0, then=Value(MAX_INT)),
        default='price',
        output_field=IntegerField(),
    )
).order_by('my_price')
```

Edited: Fix bug as per @ivan's answer and comment.

Comment: I deleted this answer when I saw @ivan's answer, because I'am serveral mimutes late for a similar answer. Then I notice there's a "-1" for this answer, I don't know why this answer deserve a "-1" even though it has an error, so I decide to undelete it.

Comment: In fact, it has two errors: first, this: `BIG_VALUE = 999999999 # or sys.maxint?` Where does `999999999` come from? And `sys.maxint` depends on the platform, which in some cases will be 64 bit and 32 in others etc. Then `order_by('-my_price')` is also wrong -- it orders in descending order, while the question asks to make it ascending, with exception to 0-priced items, that should come last.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But I think when someone answered a question, he did not deserve downvotes as long as the answer is not meaningless. An answer may not be correct, but can give a direction.